# How to create a device in IoT Hub via REST API or SDK

Tags: java, azure, device, azure-iot-hub

I want to create a device in the IoT Hub when I add a device in my application.

I'm looking for REST Endpoints available for performing operation. Or any SDK available to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the following docs:

[Service - Create Or Update Device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/createorupdatedevice)

[Control access to IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security)

example of the creating *DeviceX* with auto-generated symmetric keys:

```
PUT https://myIoTHubName.azure-devices.net/devices/DeviceX?api-version=2018-06-30
```

headers:

```
Authorization: sasToken(see the above link)
```

payload:

```
{
  "deviceId": "DeviceX"
}
```

Comment: Hi, It would be great if you can elaborate the command that you have given, I am trying to achieve the same flow.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-getstarted.md) you can find an example of how to using ServiceClient JAVA SDK. For connection string, you can use IoT Hub Owner from shared access policies. If you want a more restrictive approach, make sure you select only registry read and write for this operation.